# Inconsistent treatment of Vim and Emacs proposals?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I don't mean to bring an editor flamewar here (well, maybe a little), but [Vim proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24224/hjkl) (not the only one) was closed, and [Emacs proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9013/emacs) is given the green light.

Why the inconsistency?

I'm not trying to get Emacs proposal closed, but rather, I'm hopeful for getting Vim proposal reinstated. People like me who are tired of having godawful ad-laden `vim.w**kia.com` as top Google search result for everything Vim will understand me.

Comment: It was closed as a duplicate, but I did not where it was stated which proposal it was a duplicate of.

Comment: @Geoffrey there was another proposal, but it appears to be deleted.

Comment: /me brings the popcorn and settles comfortably to watch the fireworks ;)

Comment: The Emacs one is in commitment now

Answer (score 4):

I agree that it should be consistent. 
IMO, it seems a little bit too much to create brand new separate sites for Vim and Emacs.

As a vim user myself, I would be most glad if the central place for vim questions, were on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim because many vim question are tightly coupled with questions about sed, awk, external shell commands, and after all vim itself is a text editor originating in unix (I know, it can be run on Windows, too, But it's still a Unix tool)

Now, I don't know if other vim users think like me (and I surely don't know how emacs users feel about it)... But, if they do, there's your answer..

Comment: I'd be glad to ask it in another place, but, alas, Area51 does not appear to have a "meta" cousin, and commenting on proposals does not seem like a good place to be heard. With that said, Vim indeed may have Windows-specific questions, which will probably get closed at unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yes *may have*.. How often do you think that would actually happen? Most questions would probably be just vim-specific. And most people that know vim well, are probably using unix, and their collective knowledge would be most available/concentrated on unix.se (hopefully).

Comment: And even if there are windows specific questions, they would arguably still be on-topic on Unix.SE because it is a unix tool, albeit ported on windows

Comment: Ongoing discussion on Unix.SE.meta: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309/are-questions-about-vi-vim-and-other-clones-on-topic-here/311#311

Comment: There is no Area 51 Meta - all concerns about Area 51 are asked here. This is explained in the FAQ and in the original blog announcement. So it's on-topic to ask here. ♪

Answer (score 2):

#### Sites "will be evaluated in time"

As I noted [on the proposal site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9013/emacs), I had asked Robert Cartaino this question before. The exchange was simply a little hard to find.

The conversation [took place in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/250583#250583), and here is his answer:

> *@MarkC* If the on-topic questions are covered by an existing site (mostly programmers.SE and Stack Overflow for the programming-related topics), they will be deleted. Any site along those lines that are still there just means I have not gotten around to it, yet.
>
> My first priority is to stay on top of new proposals and proposals *as they pass into commitment*. The rest will be evaluated in time.

Answer (score 1):

Why a separate site.

Can't we just have one for development tools like editors, ide's, profiles, version control systems, etc.?

Comment: ..or that. There are already 2665 questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim Many questions which were already asked and answered here would be asked again elsewhere

Comment: This site exists : it is StackOverflow. :). I guess the issue with Vim is that for some people it is a coding tool and for other it is way to work by ssh on some server files. Depending on which kind of user you are, you will tend to look either on SO or unix (or even ServerFault). My position would be to kept everything on SO because it is the largest question pool for now. (On the other hand if all questions can be migrated elsewhere I'll be ok with that).